# Using arrays in ZSH

Tags: shell-script, zsh

I have the following statement:

```
TOKENARRAY=($TOKEN)
```

`$TOKEN` is a numeric variable.

If I try this:

```
echo ${TOKENARRAY[0]}
```

it shows me an empty string.

If I do:

```
echo ${TOKENARRAY:0}
```

it shows me the token

But the really strange thing is that if I do:

```
echo ${TOKENARRAY[1]}
```

it shows me the token.

What's going on here?
This script is supposed to work in bash, but it's not working in zsh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a script that works in both bash and zsh, you need to use a more complicated syntax.

Eg, to reference the first element in an array:

```
${array[@]:0:1}
```

Here, `array[@]` is all the elements, `0` is the offset (which *always* is 0-based), and `1` is the number of elements desired.

Comment: That will work for tokens indeed; for those needing words (as split by the shell, i.e. space, newline...) you can use the construct: `$array[(w)1]` to reference the first element (zsh starts at index 1 by default) and `${(w)#words}` to get the number of words. NB zsh only!!

Answer (score 4):

This behaviour might surprise you, depending on your programming background, but it is the desired one.

From `man zshparam` regarding the form `${TOKENARRAY[exp]}`:

> A subscript of the form `[exp]` selects the single element exp, where exp is an arithmetic expression which will be subject to arithmetic expansion  as  if  it were  surrounded by `$((...))`.  **The elements are numbered beginning with 1, unless the KSH_ARRAYS option is set in which case they are numbered from zero.**

The syntax `${TOKENARRAY:0}` is documented in `man zshexpn`:

> `${name:offset}` (...) A positive offset is always treated as the offset of a character or element in name from the first character     or element of the array (this is different from native zsh subscript notation).  **Hence 0 refers to the first          character or element regardless of the setting of the option KSH_ARRAYS.**

So this in principle gives your *complete* array (not only the first element), starting from the first character.

So, when you state

> This script is supposed to work in bash, but it's not working in zsh.

you might want to consider `emulate sh` in your script, which enables the KSH_ARRAY option besides other ones (`emulate -l sh` gives you a list) or just `setopt KSH_ARRAYS`.